# Django get fields of ForeignKey object in models

Tags: python, django, oop

I have these two models defined with a one to many relationship

from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
   from django.db import models

```
class Template(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fields = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Page(models.Model):
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template, related_name='pages')

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    text = []

    for i in range(template.fields):   #Error occuring here
        text[i] = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I want to get the value of template.fields, but I get this error

```
for i in range(template.fields):
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

Am I using the ForeignKey Object wrong? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: This doesn't make sense any sense at all. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: So the Page will have a varying number of text fields dependent on what is defined in its parent Template. Daniel Roseman

Comment: You are accessing `template` in the class body, so it's just a class and not actual data. Once you have an *instance* of that model you can access fields thought `template`.

Comment: Grimmy, Thanks a lot for your comment, how should I resolve this? Create an __init__() function?

Comment: No. This isn't a thing you solve in the model. A model represents a database table, so how can you have a varying number of fields. You need to rethink your models: probably you need a separate Field model with a ForeignKey back to Page.

Comment: Ok thanks, will try that Daniel Roseman

Comment: Add another model for the page text and let it have a foreign key to the page. Make sure you define its `reverse_name` so you can access all the text entries from the `Page` model directly. Remove anything to do with text in `Page`.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/ See example here were a reporter can have multiple articles, but the reporter model does deal with the articles directly. It's pointed to by the articles instead and django ORM makes them available through the `reverse_name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get data to iterate template field. If you modify it,use `__init__` function.

```
class Template(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fields = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Page(models.Model):
    template = models.ForeignKey(Template, related_name='pages')

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    text = []

    def __init__(self, request, *args,**kwargs):
        super (Page,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['template'].queryset = Template.objects.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```